# Cron is not echoing correct value inside cron but outside works fine

Tags: bash, shell, cron, bitcoin

I even included `source /home/user/.bashrc; <my scripts>` in crontab, still it does not output correct thing.

I have a while loop in my script which checks some value from a service called zend. It is like bitcoind but for Zen. The function looks like this, I put it [here](https://codeshare.io/axnPzD)     `check_existing_balance_withoutfl` should be greater than 0 but it is saying that it is 0 when I run from cron.

```
{

declare -i bal;
bal=0

while [ $bal -le 1 ]
do
    # #code to send zen to z addresses
    echo "Balance is $check_t_balance";
    logger "Balance is $check_t_balance";
    sleep 5

    # This following line is essential at this particular place
    export_address=$(zen-cli listaddresses | jq -r '.[2]');

    if python -c "import sys; sys.exit(0 if float($check_t_balance) <= float($min_ask_zen) else 1)"; # # for test
    # # if python -c "import sys; sys.exit(0 if float($check_t_balance) >= float($min_ask_zen) else 1)"; 

        # if [ $(bc <<< "$check_t_balance >= $min_ask_zen") -eq 1 ]; 

        then

        #statements

        echo "ZEN balance is sufficient"
        echo
        echo "We have received $check_t_balance zen in $export_address this t address"
        echo
        echo "Now, this will be sent to two z-addresses" && echo
        logger "Now, this will be sent to two z-addresses" && echo

        # # Recommended tx_fee is >= 0.0001
        # # Increse here if needed
        # tx_fee=0.0001;

        amt_aft_txfee=$(python -c "print(float($check_t_balance-$tx_fee))");
        amt=$(python -c "print(float($amt_aft_txfee/2))");
        echo "Sending now.... $amt ZEN to two z addresses"

        topUpzksnark;
        # # zen-cli z_sendmany $new_imported_address '[{"address": "'$(zen-cli z_getnewaddress)'", "amount": $amt},{"address": "'$(zen-cli z_getnewaddress)'", "amount": $amt}]';
        echo "$amt ZEN is sent to two Z addresses"

        else

            echo "ZEN balance is not suffiecient"
            moreZentoSend=$(python -c "print(float($min_ask_zen-$check_t_balance))")
            echo "Please send at least $moreZentoSend Zen to $export_address this address" >> /home/rock64/log.txt
            logger "Please send at least "$moreZentoSend" Zen to "$export_address" this address"

            echo "bal is $bal" >> /home/rock64/log.txt
    fi

    declare -i bal;
    declare -i check_existing_balance_withoutfl;
    echo "check_existing_balance_withoutfl is $check_existing_balance_withoutfl" >>/home/rock64/log.txt;
    check_existing_balance_withoutfl=$(zen-cli z_gettotalbalance | grep total | tr -d '," ' | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d '.' | bc);
    # check_existing_balance_withoutfl=$((10#$(zen-cli z_gettotalbalance | grep total | tr -d '," ' | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d '.')));
    # check_existing_balance_withoutfl=$((10#$check_existing_balance_withoutfl));
    bal+=$check_existing_balance_withoutfl;
    echo "check_existing_balance_withoutfl is $check_existing_balance_withoutfl" >>/home/rock64/log.txt;
    echo "bal is $bal after if else" >>/home/rock64/log.txt

done
}
```

logs when `sudo crontab -e` used with `55 8 * * * source /home/rock64/.bashrc; /home/rock64/light.sh > /home/rock64/both.log 2>&1`>

```
check_existing_balance_withoutfl is 0
bal is 0 after if else
There is not enough balance in the node T Address 
check_existing_balance_withoutfl is 0
check_existing_balance_withoutfl is 0
bal is 0 after if else
```

If I run the script not from crontab, everything works normal as usual.

```
$ check_existing_balance_withoutfl=$(zen-cli z_gettotalbalance | grep total | tr -d '," ' | cut -d ':' -f2 | tr -d '.' | bc)
rock64@cheese:~$ echo $check_existing_balance_withoutfl
498
```

Why bal is not 498 then, when it was executed from cron? I have literally no idea, what is wrong I am doing.

After looking at the `bash -x` log as suggested by @Marcel, it seems, I found the problem. Since, I put my script in `sudo crontab -e`, it was referring to a config file in /home/root/.zen directory, so for the zend client I had to replace all `zen-cli` lines with `zen-cli -conf=/home/user/.zen/zen.conf` in my script. Same applies to `bitcoind`, if someone ever wants to put `bitcoin-cli` in crontab to check some specific transactions or whatever.

Comment: What's your cron entry? Which file is it in - or what command did you use to add it? Do you have a _small_ segment of code that illustrates the problem? Please share that with us here in your question.

Comment: I used `sudo crontab -e` I used this `55 8    *   *   *       source /home/rock64/.bashrc; /home/rock64/light.sh > /home/rock64/both.log 2>&1` . I will put `@reboot` when it works or if it works. I have also tried running it from systemd, same issue

Comment: execute your script with `bash -x script` in your cronjob and log the output.

Comment: @Marcel here are the logs [link](https://pastebin.com/sDZE1UBJ)

Comment: @RakibFiha Please show sourcecode and output in your question and add all clarification to the question, not in comments or on external servers.

Comment: @Bodo updated, the latter log asked in the comment is too long.

Comment: I cannot access the link that is supposed to show your log, and the external content may get removed later leaving the question less useful. Please show also the code that sets variables `check_t_balance` and `min_ask_zen` and that calls the function.

Comment: @Bodo I found the problem, and updated the question with an answer at the end.

Comment: Why do you put your `cron` job into `root`'s crontab? Does it have to be run as `root`?

Comment: yeah, otherwise, it asks for the password, because I was aiming to automate some systemctl commands using that script

Comment: Pleased you've got a solution. But please don't put your answer in the question. Put it in an answer - and then accept your own answer with the tick mark. That's how these sites work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the `bash -x` log as suggested by @Marcel, it seems, I found the problem.

Since, I put my script in `sudo crontab -e`, it was referring to a config file in `/home/root/.zen` directory.

So for the `zend` client to work under `sudo crontab -e` or `/etc/crontab` I had to replace all `zen-cli` lines with `zen-cli -conf=/home/<yourusername>/.zen/zen.conf` in my script. Same applies to `bitcoind`,

Do not use `$USER` in `<yourusername>` since it will be root under `sudo crontab -e`, so rather use the full name of the user or specify in a variable for the username.

If someone ever wants to use `bitcoin-cli` in `sudo crontab -e` to check some specific transactions or something that requires password during system bootup or any other functions, you can replace

`bitcoin-cli` with `bitcoin-cli -conf=/home/<yourusername>/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

So, for example to check latest block instead of doing

`bitcoin-cli getblockcount` do:

`bitcoin-cli -conf=/home/<yourusername>/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf getblockcount`

Comment: So, why do you use `sudo crontab`? Why aren't you using your *own* crontab?

Comment: In the script, there are some systemctl commands which require the sudo password. Is there any alternative to `sudo crontab` for this scenario?